# How could I know it's initial rendering in `getDerivedStateFromProps` react.js lifecycle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react.js v 16.3 and I'm confused by `getDerivedStateFromProps` a little bit.

I want to have `state` updated but I want **particular** changes to the state on the initial rendering only. How could I determine - is it first rendering or not?

Answer (score 0):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` takes 2 arguments: `nextProps` and `prevState`. You could check `prevState` to determine is it initial rendering or not.

Basically, `prevState` is `null` in the first `getDerivedStateFromProps` call. So, you could easily do:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState === null) { return whatever_you_want } 
}
```

If there is some default state in the component by the way, you could extract it to variable:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { sentence: 'bla-bla-bla' }

class Paragraph extends React.Component {
  state = INITIAL_STATE

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState === INITIAL_STATE) { return whatever_you_want }

    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Even if you use `getDerivedStateFromProps` to calculate your state, you should always set your initial state in constructor. React will actually complain if you don't do this - see example below:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    setState({bar: 10})
  }
}
```

This will result in following warning:

*`Foo` uses `getDerivedStateFromProps` but its initial state is undefined. This is not recommended. Instead, define the initial state by assigning an object to `this.state` in the constructor of `Foo`. This ensures that `getDerivedStateFromProps` arguments have a consistent shape.*

This means that checking if `prevState` is undefined is not a viable option, as it is a good practice to set the state in constructor. Instead you can either check if `bar` has a valid value or use some kind of flag:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      bar: 0,
      inited: false
    }
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if(prevState.inited) {
      setState({
        bar: 20
      })
    } else {
      setState({
        bar: 10,
        inited: true
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` does not call `setState`, as it's static. It returns a new state intead.